# Xcode automatic signin with github actions?

Tags: ios, xcode, github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I want to have a github actions workflow to build my debug and release build automatically when I push on my branch with fastlane but I had some issues and wanted to see if some people had some inputs:

At first I wanted to use the auto xcode signin but fastlane kept saying that I had to account linked on xcode so I tried to use this in fastlane:

```
  lane :myLaneToBuildDev do
    increment_build_number(xcodeproj: "App/App.xcodeproj")
    build_app(workspace: "App.xcworkspace", scheme: "App", configuration: "Debug", export_method: "ad-hoc", xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates -authenticationKeyID #{ENV["APPSTORE_CONNECT_API_KEY"]} -authenticationKeyIssuerID #{ENV["APPSTORE_CONNECT_ISSUER_ID"]} -authenticationKeyPath #{File.expand_path('pathToP8')}")
    firebase_app_distribution(app: ENV["FIREBASE_PRO_APP_ID"], service_credentials_file: ENV["SERVICE_CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH"], groups: "developers", release_notes: "Lots of amazing new features to test out!")
    slack(message: "Successfully distributed a new Firebase build for app", slack_url: ENV["FASTLANE_SLACK_URL"], channel: ENV["FASTLANE_SLACK_CHANNEL"])
  end
```

I think it's supposed to work with the automatic sign in from xcode, I have no more sign in error but my build is blocking on generating dSYM step.

```
[12:37:20]: ▸ Compiling LaunchScreen.storyboard
[12:37:20]: ▸ Processing App.plist
[12:37:21]: ▸ Linking App
[12:37:22]: ▸ Generating 'App.app.dSYM'
##[debug]Re-evaluate condition on job cancellation for step: 'Run fastlane'.
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

I also tried to download all the provisionning profiles and setup the certificates in the github actions workflow to try to sign in this way but I still had the "no account error":

```
name: Build
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'releases/app-**'

concurrency:
  group: build-ios-${{ github.ref }}
  cancel-in-progress: true
  
jobs:
  build:
    permissions: write-all
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - uses: actions/cache@v2
      with:
        path: Pods
        key: ${{ runner.os }}-pods-${{ hashFiles('**/Podfile.lock') }}
        restore-keys: |
          ${{ runner.os }}-pods-
          
    - name: Install the Apple certificate and provisioning profile
      env:
          PROD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.IOS_PROD_P12 }}
          DEV_CERTIFICATE_BASE64: ${{ secrets.IOS_DEV_P12 }}
          P12_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.P12_PASSWORD }}
          KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD }}
      run: |
          echo $PROD_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 | base64 --decode > prod.p12
          echo $DEV_CERTIFICATE_BASE64 | base64 --decode > dev.p12
          security create-keychain -p $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD build.keychain
          security default-keychain -s build.keychain
          security unlock-keychain -p $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD build.keychain
          security import prod.p12 -k build.keychain -P $P12_PASSWORD -T /usr/bin/codesign
          security import dev.p12 -k build.keychain -P $P12_PASSWORD -T /usr/bin/codesign
          security set-key-partition-list -S apple-tool:,apple:,codesign: -s -k $KEYCHAIN_PASSWORD build.keychain

    - name: 'Download Provisioning Profiles Dev'
      uses: apple-actions/download-provisioning-profiles@v1
      if: contains(github.ref, 'releases/app')
      with: 
        bundle-id: 'com.*.*.dev'
        profile-type: 'IOS_APP_DEVELOPMENT'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}

    - name: 'Download Provisioning Profiles Prod'
      uses: apple-actions/download-provisioning-profiles@v1
      if: contains(github.ref, 'releases/app')
      with: 
        bundle-id: 'com.*.*'
        profile-type: 'IOS_APP_STORE'
        issuer-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_ISSUER_ID }}
        api-key-id: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_KEY_ID }}
        api-private-key: ${{ secrets.APPSTORE_PRIVATE_KEY }}
  

    - name: Set up netrc file for mapbox
      run: echo "machine api.mapbox.com" > ~/.netrc && echo "login mapbox" >> ~/.netrc && echo "password ${{ secrets.MAPBOX_SECRET }}" >> ~/.netrc

    - name: Bundle dependencies
      run: bundle install

    - name: CocoaPods dependencies
      run: bundle exec pod install

    - name: Run fastlane
      run: bundle exec fastlane myLaneToBuildDev

    - name: Clean up keychain and provisioning profile
      if: ${{ always() }}
      run: |
        security delete-keychain build.keychain
        cat /Users/runner/Library/Logs/gym/*-*.log
```

Also my app is made with frameworks to be a bit modular because I have 2 apps and share some codes between the 2 (but the frameworks are not supposed to be signed)

So to conclude my questions:

1. Is the way of using the appstore connect api key is supposed to work with the automatic signin with xcode ? If yes, I can remove my provisionning download steps and all my p12 and certificates setup ?
2. Even if I downloaded all the certificates and provisionning profile with the workflow I had sign in issues as if the xcode account takes priority even if not setup ?
3. Why the build is blocking on the generating dSYM step ? Can it be linked to the sign ? Maybe it can't log in with the keys but I have no error

Thanks for reading and sorry for the long post !

EDIT: Finally i succeed to fix my issue, it was a conflict between the fact i download the certificates and create a keychain with them and between the fact that i'm using appstore connect automatic authentication...

So i removed all the part where i download certificates and provisionning profiles